# How to change the timeout in composed futures?

Tags: scala, actor, akka

In the example from the akka 1.1 documentation on [composing futures](http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.1.3/scala/futures.html#composing-futures), I'm wondering how it's possible to programmatically set the timeout of the generated future. I'm aware that I can adjust the global timeout in *akka.conf*, but I want to do it in place only for this piece of code.

The example code looks as follows

```
val f1 = actor1 !!! msg1
val f2 = actor2 !!! msg2

val f3 = for {
   a: Int    <- f1
   b: Int    <- f2
   c: String <- actor3 !!! (a + b)
} yield c

val result = f3.get()
```

Am I right that akka creates a total of four futures in this example?

- One for each message send to actor1, 2 and 3
- One to wrap these three futures

It's easy to change the timeouts in the first case, e.g.

```
val f1 = actor1 !!! (msg1, 15000)  // sets timeout to 15 seconds
```

but how can I Set the timeout for the wrapping future? Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There would actually be 6 futures total I believe, the 3 you got from the actors, and 1 for each flatMap/map method.

The timeout for the 3 actor futures are set just like you stated, but the 3 wrapper futures will inherit the timeout from the future on the right hand side of each section of the for-comprehension. However, the returned future will use the timeout of the first future in the for-comprehension.

For Akka 2.0 this will change to allow an implicit timeout to be specified, as long as no issues pop up during testing.

Comment: Thanks, that was the information I needed. So until Akka 2.0 is released I'll increase the timeout of the first future. This works for my purpose, although setting it explicitly would be nicer.